# Bitcoin Debit Card without a phone (number)

Tags: payment, banks, debitcard, fiat, visa

Where can I signup for a bitcoin debit card without a phone?

There are a number of "bitcoin debit card" providers -- services that issue you a traditional visa/mastercard/etc debit card that allows you to pay for purchases in fiat, but where the balance of the card is automatically converted from your cryptocurrency balance stored on their custodial wallet.

> Note that a "bitcoin debit card" is distinct from gift cards in that the balance lives in an account *below* the debit card, not on the card itself. This is important because otherwise you may end-up with tons of different cards with low balances. It's important for my business that I can pay invoices with a single card, and if that card expires then the balance can simply be spent on the card's replacement.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find any providers that do not require a phone to be linked to the account.

For security reasons, I do not mix insecure devices like my phone with high-risk accounts like financial services. Therefore, it's important that I find financial services that don't require a phone number to be linked to the account (shudder at the thought of implementing 2FA over SMS) or an app.

Coinsbank requires a phone number. Wirex requires a phone number. Cryptopay requires an app (which grants access to the account to a phone). Unbanked (Ternio) is dead.

Where can I get a "bitoin debit card" without a phone?

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately any requests for service recommendations or reviews are off-topic here. Those sort of topics tend to outdate quickly, tend to get poorly argued answers, and attract a lot of spam, so we no longer collect them.

Comment: @Murch can you at least recommend an alternative forum where such a question is appropriate and will likely yield useful answers?

Comment: You could perhaps try /r/bitcoin or Stacker.news?